# Type Lists with constraints

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints, constraint-kinds

I'm trying to build a list at the type level, but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to enforce constraints.

My base code is:

```
data Foo z q = Foo1 (z q)
             | Foo2 (z q)

class Qux q -- where ...
class Baz z -- where ...

class Bar a where             -- a has kind *->*
  type BCtx a q :: Constraint -- using ConstraintKinds to allow constraints on the concrete type
  f :: (BCtx a q) => a q -> a q -> a q
  g :: (BCtx a q, BCtx a q') => a q -> a q'

instance (Baz z) => Bar (Foo z) where
  type BCtx (Foo z) q = (Num (z q), Qux q) -- for example
  f (Foo1 x) (Foo1 y) = Foo1 $ x+y -- these functions need access to the type q to do arithmetic mod q
  f (Foo1 x) (Foo2 y) = Foo2 $ x-y
  -- ...
```

You can think of the `q`s above representing prime powers. I would also like to represent composite numbers using a type list of `qi`s. I'm imagining something like:

```
data QList qi qs = QCons qi qs
                 | QNil
```

with the data

```
data FList c q = FNil 
               | FCons (c (Head q)) (FList c (Tail q))
```

where `(Head q)` should correspond to `qi` and `(Tail q)` should correspond to `qs`. Note that the `q` parameter for `FList` is NOT (necessarily) a `(Qux q)`, it is a *list* of `(Qux qi)`. (I don't want to flesh out anything more about this list, since it's one of the design problems I'm posing). I would like to work "modulus-wise" on the `FList`:

```
instance (Bar c) => Bar (FList c) where
   type BCtx (FList c) q = () -- Anything I put here is not enough
   f (FCons x xs) (FCons y ys) = FCons (f x y) (f xs ys)
   -- the left call to `f` calls a concrete instance, the right call to `f` is a recursive call on the rest of the list
   -- ...
```

Compiling these codes snippets together in GHC result in (modulo transcription, abstraction, and typing errors):

```
Could not deduce (BCtx c (Head q), BCtx c (Tail q))
```

and then

```
Could not deduce (BCtx c (Head (Tail q)), BCtx c (Tail (Tail q)))
```

etc.

I see why I'm getting this error, but not how to fix it.

Concretely, I'm expecting an `FList c q` type where `c~Foo z` and `q~QCons q1 (QCons q2 QNil)`, and of course my list *will* satisfy all of the BCtx constraints at every level.

I'm not sure that fixing those particular errors will result in compiling code, but it is a start. The entire Bar class is basically fixed (the Constraint kind is required, and the instances of Bar must have kind * -> *). I don't believe I can use existential types to create a list of generic objects because I need access to the `qi` parameter. I am willing to change the type of `FList` and `QList` to allow me to *work modulus-wise on a collection of Bars*.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle type lists, it's necessary to discriminate empty from nonempty lists and handle them separately.  The 'Could not deduce' errors in your code occur because your instance assumes a nonempty list, when in fact the list may or may not be empty.  Here is a solution using the extensions `TypeFamilies`, `TypeOperators`, `DataKinds`, and `GADTs`.

With `DataKinds`, type lists are predefined.  They have kind `[*]`, but they'll be used in a context where kind `*` is expected, so an operator is needed to cast them:

```
data InjList (qs :: [*])
```

Using type lists, `FList` is defined as

```
data FList c q where
  FNil :: FList c (InjList '[])
  FCons :: c h -> FList c (InjList t) -> FList c (InjList (h ': t))
```

It's defined as a GADT to express how it's only possible to construct `FList`s over the type `InjList q'` for some type-list `q'`.  For instance, the term `FCons [True] FNil` has type `FList [] (InjList (Bool ': '[]))`.  On the other hand, since `Bool` isn't of the form `InjList q'`, there are no terms (except ⊥) of type `FList [] Bool`.  By pattern matching on an `FList`, a function can verify that it has been given a non-⊥ argument, and further determine whether it's been passed an empty type list.

An instance of `Bar` for `FList`s has to handle nil lists and cons lists separately.  A nil list has an empty context.
 A cons list has components for the head and tail of the list.  This is expressed by pattern matching on the type-list in the associated type instance of `BCtx`.  The function `f` examines its argument to verify that it's not ⊥ and to decide whether it's an empty list.

```
instance (Bar c) => Bar (FList c) where
  -- Empty context for '[]
  type BCtx (FList c) (InjList '[]) = ()
  -- Context includes components for head and tail of list
  type BCtx (FList c) (InjList (h ': t)) = (BCtx c h, BCtx (FList c) (InjList t))

  f FNil FNil = FNil
  f (FCons x xs) (FCons y ys) = FCons (f x y) (f xs ys)
```

We can load the code into GHCi to verify that it works:

```
instance Bar [] where
  type BCtx [] q = Num q
  f xs ys = zipWith (+) xs ys

instance Show (FList c (InjList '[])) where
  show FNil = "FNil"

instance (Show (c h), Show (FList c (InjList t))) => Show (FList c (InjList (h ': t))) where
  show (FCons h t) = "FCons (" ++ show h ++ ") (" ++ show t ++ ")"
```

```
$ ghci

> :load Test
> f (FCons [1,2] FNil) (FCons [3,4] FNil)
FCons ([4,6]) (FNil)
```

Comment: As part of the context constraints, I think I will need to make InjList an instance of Qux. But the parameter of Qux has kind *. Is this possible? (This is one reason that all my attempts had led me to some kind of nested data of kind *).

Comment: @Eric You can probably use `instance Qux (InjList '[])` and `instance (Qux qi, Qux (InjList qs)) => Qux (InjList (qi ': qs))`.